# how to use Android Media Recorder getMaxAmplitude function

Tags: android, media, audio

I am trying to run the audio recording http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html, Its working fine, what I need is to show max amplitude while recording voice continuously. What is the best approach for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Max amplitude gives max amplitude of the given sample, so I taken sample for every 250 milli seconds and calculated max amplitude

```
public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while(i == 0) {
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                try {
                    sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (mRecorder != null) {
                    amplitude = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                    b.putLong("currentTime", amplitude);
                    Log.i("AMPLITUDE", new Integer(amplitude).toString());
                } else {
                    b.putLong("currentTime", 0);
                }
                msg.setData(b);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
```

I used message handlers to modify front end using background process thread

Answer (score 1):

Create a thread which runs all the time.
In the thread do this:

```
    int amp = mrec.getMaxAmplitude();
    if (amp > 0)
      yourcode;
```

Do you need more information on the thread?